# Execute a process always and continuosly in a single CPU Core

Tags: linux, cpu

I would like to execute a process, which always has to use only one of the CPU core, and continuously run on that single core only.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`taskset M command`

M is a bitmap that specifies CPU's – each bit corresponds to one core, so 1 means the first core, 2 the second, 4 the third etc.

Comment: k, i got it, But i studied that for permanently assign a cpu core to a single process by using isolcpus=<CPUID> to boot loader, can you explain how can i achieve this?